# Is there any case that one observer would be shared by some observables in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I think that to share one observer instance to some observables is wrong.
For example

```
Observable o1 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECOND);
Observable o2 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECOND);

Observer observer = new Observer() { ... }

o1.subscribe(observer);
o2.subscribe(observer);
```

Since the observer's onCompleted() would be called some times, it might be not acceptable.

But I could not find any documentation about this.
So, I wonder if there were any case to share one observer to some observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design the observer are created once that you subscribe to the observable, and then once that your item are emitted, your observer is unsubscribe and remove it.

What you could do is avoid to use Observables and use Relay, which it will never unsubscribe observers when it will complete since does not provide onComplete callback.

```
    /**
 * ReplayRelay it works just like hot observables, once that an observer subscribe, the Relay will replay all items already emitted
 * to another observer.
 * it should return 1,2,3,4,5 for both observers.
 */
@Test
public void testReplaytRelaySharingObserver() {
    ReplayRelay<String> relay = ReplayRelay.create();
    Subscription subscription = relay.subscribe(result -> System.out.println("Observer1:" + result));
    relay.call("1");
    relay.call("2");
    relay.call("3");
    relay.subscribe((Observer<? super String>) subscription);
    relay.call("4");
    relay.call("5");
}
```

You can see others related examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/relay/Relay.java

Comment: Thank for your information! Now, I could be sure about this. I will check RxRelay. It's so interesting!